# Show a message box from a class in c#?

Tags: c#, class, messagebox

How do you get a class to interact with the form to show a message box?

Comment: This isn't normally a good idea.  Ideally, the class should send the data back to the form and let the form show the message box.  If you code UI specifics into your class then it is completely tied to that UI.  Also, it makes unit testing impossible.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
...
MessageBox.Show("Hello World!");
```

Answer (score 15):

```
System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Hello world"); //WPF
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Hello world"); //WinForms
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Here's a message!");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class message
{
    static void Main()
    {  
        MessageBox.Show("Hello World!"); 
    }
}
```